# docker pull - invalid reference format in Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I m trying to pull images in my pipeline in a dynamic way. I have a file call "images.txt" that contain:

(cat images.txt would return)

```
 cat images.txt
    python:3.8-slim
    neo4j
```

the way to pull a image in azure pipeline is:

that code work but its not dynamic:

```
steps:
   - bash: |
         y='python:3.8-slim' 
         docker pull ${y}

    displayName: "Docker pull"
```

In azure pipelines I m doing like this:

```
 - bash: |
    #x='python:3.8-slim'
    filename='images.txt'
    n=1
    while read line; do
       echo "pulling image"
       echo ${line}
       n=$((n+1))
       docker pull ${line}
   done < $filename
```

Instead ***docker pull ${line}***
I try all kind of alternatives but none work.. I recive always the error "invalid reference format"
I tried:

```
     #eval docker pull "$line"
     #eval docker pull $line
     #eval docker pull $line
     #eval docker pull "$line"
     #eval docker pull "\${line}"
     #docker pull "\${line}"
     #docker pull $line
     #docker pull "$line"
     #docker pull $(line)
```

Any thounks would be more than apreciate

**Update**: the code provide for @Paul Rey

```
 filename='images.txt'
 n=1
 echo "docker pull"
 for line in $(cat ${filename}); 
 do
   echo ${line}
   docker pull ${line}
 done
```

it works when the image have not tag
so the image: neo4j its succesfully pulled but
with python:3.8-slim I recive the error of "invalid reference format"
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the `docker pull ${line}` is the right one. But can you ensure the `images.txt` is well formatted? I mean, it looks like there are extra spaces on every lines. Maybe there are ending lines characters too.

There is an alternative for a loop if there are only one word per lines:

```
for line in $(cat ${filename}); do
    docker pull ${line}
done
```

Comment: Hi @Paul it worked !!! thank you very very much but there is still an isue there, like you said it work for a only one word per lines (neo4j worked) how to do it with a image with tag "python:3.8-slim"

Comment: It should work the same while there is no space character :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar isue and I realice that when I was reading from the txt bash was adding a extra white space:
imagine you have in you images.txt
python:3.8-slim

you can check it like this:

```
filename='images.txt'
n=1
y=python:3.8-slim
for line in $(cat ${filename}); 
do
 z=${line}
 echo $z
 echo $y
 echo -n "$z" | wc -c
 echo -n "$y" | wc -c  
done
```

in case charachter from z and y are not the same you can remove white space so:

```
filename='images.txt'
n=1
#echo "docker pull"
for line in $(cat ${filename}); 
do
  #echo ${line}
  y=${line//[[:space:]]/}
  echo $y
  docker pull ${y}
done
```